# Twitter API Rate Limit Exceeded in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I'm trying to use the Twitter Gem for Ruby/Rails in order to check whether an account exists on Twitter with a certain username.

The problem is that after about 15 username checks, the rate limit is said to be exceeded. I understand that Twitter limits its API calls to ~15 every 15 minutes or so, but is there a way that I can check more than one usernames existence in a call?

Here is the code I am currently using to check the existence

```
def twitter_user_exists?(handle)
    $client.user(handle)
    true
rescue Twitter::Error::NotFound
    false
end
```

This executes for every username I have returning true/false based on whether the user exists.

Let me know if more information/code is needed. Thanks.

Comment: Trying to do something very similar to this but a solution was not posted here either https://twittercommunity.com/t/check-if-user-exist-without-using-api/7397

Answer (score 1):

I took a look around the Twitter gem and didn't see any other calls that would allow multiple users.

If some of the checks are being done multiple times, you could store the result of whether or not an account is valid in the database and then retrieve it from the database if it already exists. This would only be an issue if a user changes their twitter name or removes their account which probably won't happen too often.

Another option is to try to request the HTML version of the Twitter profile and see if that 404s or not. Though it is possible that Twitter will rate limit this or block you.

Comment: The first option is not possible as it needs to be checked on a repeating basis indefinitely to determine if it no longer/becomes available. The second also is unreliable as you've said